# How can I change the project web page in SourceForge?

Tags: web, sourceforge

I have a project in SourceForge: [Kryptostr](http://kryptostr.sourceforge.net/), and I want to modify the default web page. How can I do this? Can I use javascript? Can I use some kind of server web language as ASP, PHP, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check: [Project web](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Project%20Web%20Services/).

> Support for many programming
>   languages, including PHP (via
>   mod_php), Perl, Python, Tcl, Ruby, and
>   shell scripts.

Answer (score 8):

Since SourceForge's update to the new [Allura](https://forge-allura.apache.org/p/allura/) hosting software the relevant documentation is [Project Web Services](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Project%20Web%20Services/).

You can use `scp` or `sftp` or a suitable SFTP client to copy files to `$SF_USER@web.sourceforge.net:/home/project-web/$SF_PROJECT/htdocs/`

(where `$SF_USER` is your SourceForge username and `$SF_PROJECT` is the project name)

Answer (score 4):

Using FileZilla, go directly to the directory `/home/project-web/PROJECT_NAME/htdocs`
and upload your `index.html` file.